# Setting encoding for SCM Activity plugin for sonar-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I use SonarQube **4.2** with SCM Activity [scmactivity] **1.7** with sonar-maven-plugin **4.2**.

Upon executing `mvn sonar:sonar` I'm seeing the following:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:4.2:sonar (default-cli) @ ... ---
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: ...\target\sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.2
...
[INFO] [15:43:51.829] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
...
[INFO] [15:43:59.169] Sensor ScmActivitySensor...
[INFO] [15:43:59.169] Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
[INFO] [15:43:59.170] Found SCM type: svn
[INFO] [15:43:59.170] Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1250...
[INFO] [15:43:59.343] Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1250 done: 173 ms
[INFO] [15:43:59.345] Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 176 ms
```

How can the encoding be set up to another one, say UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to the `properties` section of the POM:

```
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

Comment: No change. I had `sourceEncoding` already when I asked the question and with `outputEncoding` it didn't change - still `with encoding windows-1250` after `Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US`.

Comment: I updated the logs in my question with encoding info for the different stages of the sonar execution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't. This is the line responsible for printing the encoding:

```
TimeProfiler profiler = new TimeProfiler().start("Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding " + Charset.defaultCharset());
```

However, this is somewhat misleading, because author names are always normalized and stripped of all non ascii characters:

```
authors.add(lineNumber, normalizeString(line.getAuthor()));
...
private String normalizeString(String inputString) {
  String lowerCasedString = inputString.toLowerCase();
  String stringWithoutAccents = removeAccents(lowerCasedString);
return removeNonAsciiCharacters(stringWithoutAccents);
```

So actually, the encoding has no impact.